# Spring Scheduling - Should run every minute but after midnight it stops

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have weird case.
Everything worked fine until midnight I have a log every 1 min from 5PM to 11:59PM and the last one was at 12:00AM after it stopped working. Why did it stop working after midnight? Any idea?

```java
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * ? * *") // every minute
    public void execute() {

        this.log.info("Start XYZ");
        // ... do sth execute elements
        this.log.info("Stop Xyz");
    }
```

EDIT.
I use two ThreadPoolTaskScheduler and at start I get info log:

```java
More than one TaskExecutor bean found within the context, and none is named 'taskExecutor'. Mark one of them as primary or name it 'taskExecutor' (possibly as an alias) in order to use it for async processing: [XyzThreadPoolTaskScheduler, ZxyThreadPoolTaskScheduler]
```

That's quite weird but from Friday to Saturday it stopped working, from Saturday to Sunday and from Sunday to Monday it worked properly

Comment: The correct cron for every minute would be "0 * * * * ?"

Comment: @Mar-Z I dont think so. But it should also work. I took it 0 * * ? * * from here : https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: This is for Quartz. They use 7 parameters. Check Spring cron parameters here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron()

Comment: @Mar-Z Right! However in examples are 6sign cron. Thanks, good perceptiveness! I added some mroe information in the question :)